# QR500-B Scanner in Flutter opens keyboard instead of running _handleTextInput function

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to implement a QR500-B scanner in my Flutter application, but I'm facing an issue where, upon scanning a QR code, the keyboard opens instead of triggering the _handleTextInput function.
I want the scanned data to be processed and handled within the _handleTextInput function.

I have already tried using FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()) in the didChangeDependencies method to prevent the keyboard from opening, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the _handleTextInput function is triggered upon scanning a QR code with the QR500-B scanner.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
class ExternalScanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExternalScanner({super.key});

  @override
  _ExternalScannerState createState() => _ExternalScannerState();
}

class _ExternalScannerState extends State<ExternalScanner> {
  late TextEditingController _textEditingController;
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _textEditingController.addListener(
      _handleTextInput,
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTextInput() {
    final scannedData = _textEditingController.text;

    developer.log('Scanned data: $scannedData');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Focus(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        child: TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          readOnly: true,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Scanned Data',
          ),
          onTap: () {
            _focusNode.requestFocus();
            SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```